# Live updates using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

At the moment, I have a Javascript (JQuery) front-end which periodically makes requests to a seperate, PHP script which returns posts.

For the sake of efficiency, however, I'd like to simply add **new** results to the array, not even looking at existing posts.

As it stands, I've attempted to do so with times (i.e. "SELECT * FROM table WHERE time >= $time"), however, have realized its limitations and inability to conform with my initial idea.

Are there any ideas out there? I'd much prefer to do this without having to reform my scripts into using XML to transfer the data - however, if such is the only case, I'll be happy to oblige. :)

Comment: What is wrong with using a timestamp?

Comment: Theoretically, nothing. I just haven't found a method using it that complies with my requirements and the method with which posts are retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML looked something like this (You will need to adjust it to your situation):

```
<div id="posts">
  <div id="post-1"> ... </div>
  <div id="post-2"> ... </div>
  <div id="post-3"> ... </div>
  <div id="post-4"> ... </div>
</div>
```

You could update your load request like this:

```
function loadNewPosts(){
   var id = $("#posts > div:last")[0].id.substr(4);

   $.get('/update.php', { lastId: id }, function(data){
       $("#posts").append(data);
   }, 'html');
}

window.setInterval(loadNewPosts, 1000*60*5) // every 5 minutes
```

And just look for new posts with an `id` that is greater than the last `id` on the page, and return the new ones as HTML.

**Update** If your posts are in reverse chronological order, use `:first` instead of `:last` and `prepend()` instead of `append()`

Comment: Hey Doug I know you posted this a long time ago but can you explain to me what the update.php would look like?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is lacking detail on a number of things. I am going to assume that you are periodically going to make a call to a PHP script. I will assume the the posts table has an auto increment ID. That way you can pass that to a query and get newer posts.

```
var current_id = 1234; // this will need to be filled in somehow

setInterval(get_latest_posts, 10000);

function get_latest_posts() {
  $.getJSON('/latest', {current_id: current_id}, function(data) {
    current_id = data.new_id;
    // process data.posts
  });
}
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db('...');

// retrieve newer posts
$current_id = intval($_POST['current_id']);
$sql = <<<END
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > $current_id
END;
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$new_id = $current_id;
$posts = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $posts[] = $row;
  $new_id = max($new_id, $row['id']);
}

// return the posts as a JSON object    
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
  'new_id' => $new_id,
  'posts' => $posts,
));
?>
```

There are many variations on this theme.